# How to fix the High Risk Remote Code Execution (RCE) vulnerability in System.Data.Common 4.3.0 package referenced by Telerik.UI.for.Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, security, nuget, safety-critical, rce

In Visual Studio 2022, I created a library project using .NET Core 6.0 runtime, I am using Telerik.UI.for.Blazor 3.7.0 nuget package. After recent vera code scan I found that there is a security vulnerability in the System.Data.Common 4.3.0 package which is referenced by Telerik package.

I tried to install a System.Data.Common 4.3.0 directly into the project, but the issue still arises. Looking into the official [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common) of System.Data.Common, they have not provided a update since 15/11/2016 and 4.3.0 is the latest version.

I tried to update the latest telerik version 4.4.0 and this telerik version is still using the same System.Data.Common package and same vulnerability has been detected.

Comment: Assuming [that this is the issue you're referring to](https://www.telerik.com/forums/regarding-high-risk-vulnerabilities-during-veracode-source-clear-scan) then you don't need to anything - this was fixed 3 years ago: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-republishing-of-july-2020-security-only-updates/